# mysql xml format for deducing key value pair

Tags: mysql, xml, key-value

I am trying to record a single string of xml in a mysql database as a table of key value pairs. I am trying to pass the following xml:

```
"<object><key>x</key><val>y</val><key>key2</key><val>value2</val></object>"
```

as a varchar to a stored procedure to be converted into a table of key value pairs like so:

ID  key  val

0   x    y

1   key2 value2

but I am having trouble with extract value taking the values I grab from the xml and putting them into a single column result:

```
SELECT ExtractValue('<object><key>x</key><val>y</val><key>key2</key><val>value2</val></object>','/object/key');
SELECT ExtractValue('<object><key>x</key><val>y</val><key>key2</key><val>value2</val></object>','/object/val');
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What version of MySQL?  From v5.5, you can use [`LOAD XML`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-xml.html).

Comment: That sounds heinous.  If you have the XML, why insert as a string as opposed to using some application logic to insert into table correctly rather than do a bunch of string manipulation in MySQL.

Comment: @eggyal That format does not lend itself to use of LOAD_XML. It would need to be modified.

Comment: @eggyal I believe, as Mike Brant pointed out that would require more than the simplified xml I have in my example. 

Mike, I agree that initially it sounds heinous but this is how I would like to solve my current problem and I feel like I am pretty close to a solution just with extractvalue alone.